# Django forms URLField allow empty scheme

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django form that uses a 'forms.URLField' like `local_url1 = URLField(label="First Local URL", required=False)`.  If a user inputs something like 'https://www.google.com' then the field validates without error.

However, if the user puts 'www.google.com' the field fails validation and the user sees an error.  This is because the layout of a URL is `scheme://host:port/absolute_path` and the failing URL is missing the scheme (e.g. https), which Django's URLFieldValidation expects.

I don't care if my users include the scheme and nor should my form.  Unfortunately, the error from django is completely useless in indicating what is wrong, and I've had multiple users ask why it says to enter a valid URL.  I'm also certain I've lost paying customers because of this.

Is there a way to have all the other validation of a URL take place, but ignore the fact that the scheme is missing?  At the very least, can I change the error message to add something like "Did you include http?". I've attempted implementing my own URLField and URLFieldValidation, but unless that's the path I have to take, then that is a different StackOverflow question.

I'm using Django 1.7, by the way.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

> URL/URI scheme list to validate against. If not provided, the default
>   list is ['http', 'https', 'ftp', 'ftps']. As a reference, the IANA Web
>   site provides a full list of [valid URI schemes](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml).

If the valid URI schemes provided by IANA web are not what you are looking for, then I suggest you create your own field validator.

Remember that URLField is a subclass of the CharField. and since `www.something.com` is ok with you, then It's simple to add a regular expression to the regular CharField that checks if the pattern is correct or not.

A regular expression like this for example will validate against `www` and `http://`. so with or without http or https.

```
((?:https?\:\/\/|www\.)(?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)*[-a-z0-9]+.*)
```

`www.google.com -- OK`

`http://www.google.com -- OK`

`https://www.google.com -- OK`

`http://google.com -- OK`

`https://google.com -- OK`

However, this will not complain about `blahwww.domain.com`

so you might enhance it as you like.

Comment: Thanks, @Othman.  This is similar to the path I have tried, but not exactly the same so I'll give it a shot.  It may take me some time, but if your suggestion works, I'll be sure to come back and give you the credit.

Comment: Just to add a thought: I would think it'd be better to add some pre-validation logic to add a default scheme. Seems easier, and perhaps less error-prone than re-writing a regex that isn't as well-tested as the Django URLField validator.